# OpenLayers: Attaching an ground layer image over an large building

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openlayers-3, geo

I've got the following task:

Attaching a ground layer (provided as an jpg-image) over an plant.

I thought that I've found an solution.

Live-Demo on CodePen: http://codepen.io/mizech/full/dXBoRq/

But it doesn't work as expected. If one zooms into or out the map the image doesn't scale bigger or smaller.

Moreover: The image is supposed to rotate with the map. That doesn't work neither.

Therefore my question:

**What do I have to do to make it work the way it should** (image scales when zoomed-in and -out, images follows when rotating) **?**

Or should I choose a complete different approach?

Then any hints concerning code-examples are very appreciated.

Here my code so far:

```js
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var control = new ol.control.FullScreen();

var center = ol.proj.transform([6.9690055, 49.2175355], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  position: center,
  element: document.getElementById('plant')
});

var view = new ol.View({
  center: center,
  zoom: 17
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [layer],
  controls: [control],
  overlays: [overlay],
  view: view
});
```

```css
#plant {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(16.5deg);
}

#plant img {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div id="map" class="map">
  <div id="plant"><img src="http://placehold.it/1300x400" alt="bild" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use another option to accomplish the preferred effect, there are two options I can think of:

**1.** Use `ol.layer.Image()`, code sample:

```
var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent([7.2, 49.3, 6.5, 49.1],
    'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
new ol.layer.Image({
    opacity: 0.6,
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: 'http://placehold.it/1300x400',
        imageExtent: extent
    })
})
```

The extent is just a rough estimation yet.

**2.** Use a vector Layer to style an Icon using your image, already explained here: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130603/how-to-resize-a-feature-and-prevent-it-from-scaling-when-zooming-in-openlayers-3/

To rotate it along with the map use `rotateWithView: true`  in your icon style, like this:

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Icon({
    src: 'http://placehold.it/1300x400',
    rotateWithView: true,
    opacity: 0.6
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to rotate the ol.layer.image ? I would like to rotate it around 15 degrees clockwise. So that it covers the plant. Please see here : http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/yaBOYd

Comment: I am not aware of any possibility to rotate an `ol.layer.image`, but you could rotate the image before using it in an image editor.